# source-map-explorer error: Check that you are using the correct source map

Tags: javascript, webpack, source-maps

I have a JavaScript project that uses Webpack 4 with source maps:

```
mode: 'development',
entry: { app: './src/app.js' },
output: {
    filename: 'app.[contenthash].js',
    path: outputPath,
},
devtool: 'sourcemap',
externals,
....
```

It generates 2 JS files in my `dist` folder:
`app.[contenthash].js` and `app.[contenthash].js.map` attached to it.

I installed `source-map-explorer`:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer

But when i run it on these files, i get the error:

> Your source map refers to generated column 8 on line 17, but the
>   source only contains 0 column(s) on that line.   Check that you are
>   using the correct source map.

How can i fix that?

**EDIT:**

When i change Webpack's mode to `production` it's not throwing that error. Why?
Now with `production` mode, it just hangs when i run it.. how long does it suppose to take?

Answer (score 39):

This answer is based on @piecioshka's ~ but disables column/line mapping check, as indicated in this [source-map-explorer#README](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer)

The full command looks as:

```sh
npx source-map-explorer dist/main.js --no-border-checks
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. I made a general mistake: not generated a minified version.

`source-map-explorer` based on two files:

- `bundle.js` — a **minified** version
- `bundle.js.map` — source maps (generated for `bundle.js`)

---

**Step 1.** Build a dist file + source maps

eg. via `webpack`

```
npx webpack -p src/main.js --production --devtool source-map
```

eg. via `rollup`

```
npx rollup -i src/main.js -o dist/bundle.js -m
```

**Step 2.** Audit by

```
npx source-map-explorer dist/main.js
```